# Try anidado no captura

Tags: java, bucle-for, try-catch

1.Si no entiendo mal el `try` interno hace la iteración y cuando alcanza `i(6)` se genera una excepción que el `catch` interno no captura porque no es su cometido. Pero supongo que captura el `catch` externo. ¿El programa finaliza porque ya se ha salido del bucle `for` y no se vuelve a iterar?`

```
class NestTrys {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Here, numer is longer than denom. 
        int numer[] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 };
        int denom[] = { 2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 8 };

        try { // outer try 
            for(int i=0; i<numer.length; i++) {
                try { // nested try 
                    System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " +
                            denom[i] + " is " +
                            numer[i]/denom[i]);
                } catch (ArithmeticException exc) {
                    // catch the exception 
                    System.out.println("Can't divide by Zero!");
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
            // catch the exception 
            System.out.println("No matching element found.");
            System.out.println("Fatal error -- program terminated.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es que no tiene sentido que se siga iterando si se produjo una `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ya que si `i` est'a fuera de rango `i + n` lo estará también

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El lenguaje java incorpora soporte para manejar situaciones anómalas, conocidas como excepciones, que pueden ocurrir durante la ejecución de un programa. Con este sistema de manipulación de excepciones un programa puede comunicar eventos inesperados a un contexto de ejecución más capacitado para responder a tales eventos anormales. Estas excepciones son manejadas por código fuera del flujo normal de control del programa.

En el ejemplo que tienes, el try-catch externo se encarga de detectar y atrapar las excepciones que puedan ocurrir en el ciclo for, mientras que el try-catch interno solo se encarga de atrapar las excepciones o errores que puedan ocurrir al hacer la división. Algo muy importante que debes recordar es que cuando ocurre una excepción en el código dentro del try se interrumpe el flujo normal del programa y la ejecución se salta al bloque try (por lo que, si había más código despues de las líneas que producen la excepción, este código ya no se ejecuta) Para entender mejor como funciona el código hay que analizar paso a paso que es lo que ocurre en cada iteración:

```
Para i=0:
```

Se divide `numer[0]/denom[0]` = 4/2 = 2. 
    Cómo no hay ninguna excepción que atrapar el ciclo pasa a su siguiente iteración

```
Para i=1:
```

Se divide `numer[1]/denom[1]` = 8/0 = NaN. 
    Cómo dividir un número entre 0 produce una indterminación, se lanza la excepción Arithmetic Exception, la cual se atrapa en el bloque catch, y se muestra el mensaje "Can't divide by zero!" y el ciclo pasa a suguiente iteración.

```
Para i=2:
```

Se divide `numer[2]/denom[2]` = 16/4 = 4. 
    Cómo no hay ninguna excepción que atrapar el ciclo pasa a su siguiente iteración

```
Para i=3:
```

Se divide `numer[2]/denom[2]` = 32/4 = 8. 
    Cómo no hay ninguna excepción que atrapar el ciclo pasa a su siguiente iteración

```
Para i=4:
```

El mismo caso que en i=1, Se divide `numer[4]/denom[4]` = 64/0 = NaN. Se lanza la excepción Arithmetic Exception, la cual se atrapa en el bloque catch, y se muestra el mensaje "Can't divide by zero!" y el ciclo pasa a su siguiente iteración.

```
Para i=5:
```

Se divide `numer[5]/denom[5]` = 128/8 = 16. 
    Cómo no hay ninguna excepción que atrapar el ciclo pasa a su siguiente iteración

```
Para i=6:
```

Aquí es donde se presenta el error: como la posición numer[6] sí existe, no hay ningún problema para entrar al ciclo.

**Una vez en el ciclo, se intenta hacer la operación `numer[6]/denom[6]`, pero al no existir denom[6], se produce una excepción de tipo ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Entonces la ejecución salta al bloque catch dentro del ciclo, pero como la excepción que atrapa es de otro tipo, la excepción no puede ser tratada; el ciclo se interrumpe y la ejecución se salta hasta otro bloque catch que pueda tratar la excepción, que en este caso es el segundo catch del código.**

Una vez atrapada la excepción, se muestra el mensaje "No matching element found.
Fatal error -- program terminated."

Despues de eso el programa termina pues porque no hay más código que ejecutar.

Para evitar que el ciclo for se interrumpa puedes incluir otro bloque catch, pero que capture excepciones de tipo ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. De esta forma cuando el ciclo llega a i=6 e i=7 y se produzca la excepción, el programa primero va a 'revisar' el tipo de excepción del primer bloque catch, como no coincide con su tipo, va a saltar al siguiente bloque catch, comprobando que puede tratar excepciones del tipo ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Entra al bloque y ejecuta el código, como ya se atrapó la excepción, el programa no interrumpe el ciclo.

Haciendo eso el código quedaría asi:

```
class NestTrys {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Here, numer is longer than denom. 
    int numer[] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 };
    int denom[] = { 2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 8 };

    try { // outer try 
        for(int i=0; i<numer.length; i++) {
            try { // nested try 
                System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " + denom[i] + " is " + numer[i]/denom[i]);
            } catch (ArithmeticException exc) {
                // catch the exception 
                System.out.println("Can't divide by Zero!");
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
            // catch the exception 
                System.out.println("Ocurre una excepción en i="+i);
                System.out.println("Pero el ciclo no se interrumpe");
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
        // catch the exception 
        System.out.println("No matching element found.");
        System.out.println("Fatal error -- program terminated.");
    }
}
```

}

Nota como despues de un bloque try puedes escribir varios bloques catch, los que creas que son necesarios para tu programa. Entonces como ya estás capturando los dos tipos de excepciones que pueden ocurrir dentro del ciclo (que no haya más elementos en un vector, y la división entre cero), el catch 'externo' sale sobrando. Y si lo eliminas el código quedaría así:

```
class NestTrys {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Here, numer is longer than denom. 
    int numer[] = { 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 };
    int denom[] = { 2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 8 };

    for(int i=0; i<numer.length; i++) {
        try { // nested try 
            System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " + denom[i] + " is " + numer[i]/denom[i]);
        } catch (ArithmeticException exc) {
            // catch the exception 
            System.out.println("Can't divide by Zero!");
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
        // catch the exception 
            System.out.println("Ocurre una excepción en i="+i);
            System.out.println("Pero el ciclo no se interrumpe porque estoy atrapando la excepción");
        }
    }      
}
```

}

Repasando, el for se interrumpe en el código de tu ejemplo porque no le dices al programa que hacer dentro del ciclo cuando no hay mas elementos del vector 'denom', que es cuando se produce la excepción ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, sólo le dices que hacer si hay algún error al hacer la división (ArithmeticException).

Cuando sales del ciclo la excepción sigue rondando por ahí, y entonces el programa busca otro catch para atraparla; es cuando entra a la parte:

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc) {
    // catch the exception 
    System.out.println("No matching element found.");
    System.out.println("Fatal error -- program terminated.");
}
```

Y se termina el programa sin hacer la iteracion 6 y 7.

Comment: menuda explicación compañero. Te la bancaste.

Comment: Bueno, sigo teniendo dudas porque se supone que el catch está, no para finalizar un programa si hay una excepción, sino para lo contrario, para que continúe a pesar de ella. El hecho de que finalice sigo pensando que es porque la excepción que captura el último catch y que pertenece a la penúltima iteración se produce fuera del ámbito de for y entonces el programa ya no puede retornar para hacer la iteración 7. He probado a hacer el try and catch dentro de su ámbito y efectivamente hace las dos capturas sin finalizar el programa a pesar del outbound.

Comment: Hola. Remarqué una parte de la respuesta que tal vez debas repasar un poco y añadí más información por si te ayuda